# Is a Samba share being used by an external system?

Tags: networking, server, samba

System A (Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS) shares a directory via Samba. On A (the server) is there a way to tell whether any other system is currently connected to the share?

The objective is to avoid shutting down A if any Samba share is in use.

An automated (shell scripted) means of doing so would be ideal, but manual is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo smbstatus
```

You can get a more compact output by running it with the -S switch:

```
sudo smbstatus -S
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to two great answers, the one in this thread from Morbius 1, here is a simple script which checks to see if the server is still serving before shutting it down.  The calling script enters a perpetual "do" loop with a call to this script, and a sleep of several minutes.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    # Check for open Samba share.
    # All shares are named "share" something,
    # so grep for "share" is usable

    smbstatus | grep -i share > /dev/nul
    samba=$?

    # Check for open NFS mount.
    # Grep for port 2049, then
    # grep that for "ESTAB"

    netstat -naptule | grep :2049 | grep ESTAB > /dev/nul
    nfs=$?

    # If either came back zero, something is active.

    if [[ $samba != 0 && $nfs != 0 ]]; then
       shutdown -h now
    fi
```